# Where to insert file path in this Java Program?

Tags: java

I am new to Java , I am currently analyzing a file compare tool with java that compare two files from this link:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/Difftextfiledifferenceutility.htm

But no where in the file, the file path is mentioned. Where should I insert the file path? I searched google and checked Java Filestram and buffer input output stream. But did not found any useful information.

I also searched stackoverflow but it seems no such question exists.

Usually, the file path should be updated in main file, right?

But it seems that is missing in main file.

```
  public static void main(String argstrings[])
      {
        if ( argstrings.length != 2 ) {
          System.err.println("Usage: diff oldfile newfile" );
          System.exit(1);
        }
        Diff d = new Diff();
        d.doDiff(argstrings[0], argstrings[1]);
        return;
      }
```

Comment: Above the code is a usage information. Read it and do that. You could run that from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly do the way juned told you but if you want to the program to be more user friendly try to manipulate the main method like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
try{
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter the path of old file");
   String oldFile = in.nextLine();
   System.out.println("Enter the path of new file");
   String newFile = in.nextLine();
   Diff d = new Diff();
   if(!oldFile.equals("") && !newFile.equals("")) {
        d.doDiff(oldFile, newFile);
    } 
}
catch (Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your program takes the file names as the parameter. So while giving the command line input you can give the full file paths. Something like this:

```
java yourClassName volume1:\dir1\filename1 volume2:\dir2\filename2
```

Comment: @user3910265 Not necessarily, if you use eclipse or other IDE, you can always provide run time arguments in Run Configuration